# Varios fallos al hacer una clase

Tags: java, java-8

Antes que nada disculpar por un titulo que no especifica mucho y es que no se me ocurrió otro mejor. Estoy haciendo un programa para clases de programación en java.

El primero problema lo encuentro en los constructores.

b) un constructor que nos permitirá indicar la capacidad inicial de
nuestro array dinámico. En caso de que la capacidad indicada sea un
valor negativo, lanzará una excepción IllegalArgumentException con el
mensaje “Tamaño no válido: ” y el tamaño solicitado

c) un constructor que nos permitirá inicializar nuestro objeto a partir de
un array de cadenas de caracteres

d) un constructor que nos permitirá inicializar nuestro objeto a partir de
otro objeto D ynStrArray

En los casos c) y d), si el argumento pasado es una referencia nula , se
lanzará una excepción I llegalArgumentException con el texto
correspondiente

El código que tengo para los constructores es el siguiente

```java
public DynStrArray() {
    this.arCadena = new String[10];
}

public DynStrArray(int n) {
    try {
        if (n >= 0) {
            this.arCadena = new String[n];
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Tamaño no valido: " + n);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public DynStrArray(String[] arCadena) {
    this.arCadena = arCadena;

    try {
        if (arCadena != null) {
            this.arCadena = arCadena;
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Valor nulo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public DynStrArray(DynStrArray d){
    try {
        if (d != null) {
            this.arCadena = d.getArCadena();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Valor nulo: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Los problemas que tengo con estos constructores:

Cuando uso el primer constructor para crear una instancia de la clase pasando por parámetro un indice cuando se lo pongo negativo no me saca el mensaje de error y continua, cuando hago un print para mostrar la instancia me peta dando un error NullPointerException. Cuando hago un print del array me sale null. En ningún momento me sale el mensaje del catch

En los otros dos le paso valores nulos pero aun así me crea la instancia sin que salga el catch

El segundo de los problemas que tengo es con un foreach. Intento a partir de un indice mover los elementos una posición para que dicho indice quede libre y así insertar en el un nuevo valor

add(i ndex, cadena ) : inserta la cadena en la posición indicada. En caso
de que la posición indicada sea incorrecta, lanzará una excepción
IndexOutOfBoundsException con el mensaje “Posición no válido: ” y la
posición solicitada. En caso de que no existiera sitio disponible, se
incrementará el tamaño del array en un 50% .

El codigo que tengo para este metodo es el siguiente

```java
public void add(int index, String s){
    try {
        while (index > this.arCadena.length - 1) {
            increment();
        }

        if (this.arCadena[index] != null || "".equals(this.arCadena[index])) {
            String[] arS = this.arCadena;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arCadena.length - 1; i++) {
                this.arCadena[i + 1] = arS[i];
            }
        }

        this.arCadena[index] = s;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Posición no válida: " + index);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Lo que me hace dejar a null el indice que quiero tener libre y copiar su valor a los siguientes obteniendo así ese valor repetido y no me almacena el valor en el indice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes una confusión cuando te piden lanzar una excepción, lo que estás haciendo es atraparla. Para lanzar excepciones debes usar la instrucción `throw` y el tipo de excepción. Por ejemplo para el constructor b sería así: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tamaño no válido: " + n);`

Te pongo una posible solución a tus apartados b, c y d:

```
//B
public DynStrArray(int n) {
    if(n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tamaño no válido: " + n);

    this.arCadena = new String[n];
}

//C
public DynStrArray(String[] arCadena) {
    if(arCadena == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El array no puede ser nulo.");

    this.arCadena = arCadena;
}

//D
public DynStrArray(DynStrArray d){
    if(d == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El objeto DynStrArray no puede ser nulo.");

    this.arCadena = d.arCadena;
}
```

Ahora todo lo que tienes que hacer es atrapar la excepción cuando creas la instancia, así:

```
try {
    DynStrArray array = new DynStrArray(-3);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

En el caso de agregar una cadena al array, yo lo haría así:

```
public void add(int index, String s){
    if(index < 0 || index >= this.arCadena.length)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Posición no válida: " + index);

    if(this.arCadena[index] == null) {
        this.arCadena[index] = s;
        return;
    }

    int nextFreeIndex = this.getNextFreeFieldIndex(index);
    if(nextFreeIndex == this.arCadena.length) {
        this.arCadena = this.rebuildArray(this.arCadena);
    }

    for(int i = nextFreeIndex - 1; i >= index; i--) {
        this.arCadena[i+1] = this.arCadena[i];
    }
    this.arCadena[index] = s;
}

private int getNextFreeFieldIndex(int fromIndex) {
    //Busca un campo libre a partir de fromIndex y devuelve el índice del primer campo libre encontrado
    //De no haber campos libres se retornaría el tamaño del array
}


private String[] rebuildArray(String[] array) {
    //Crea un nuevo array de tamaño 50% más grande que el array recibido como parámetro
    //Copia todos los elementos de array en el nuevo array
    //Devuelve el nuevo array
}
```

Y ahora debes atrapar la excepción cuando llames a esa función:

```
try {
    DynStrArray array = new DynStrArray(5);
    array.add(7, "Mi cadena");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: gracias, tal y como decías tenia una pequeña confusión con el tema y ahora ya me quedo mucho mas claro.Con respecto al método add aparte de añadir un elemento a un array con ese indice tengo que mover una posición los elemento que ya hay para poder meterlo. Ej: array de tamaño 5, donde hay información en los tres primeros indices y quieres meter información en el primero, estos elementos que tiene el array se mueven una posición de estar en los indices 0, 1, 2 a estar en los indices 1, 2, 3 para dejar libre el 0 y guardar hay el carácter

Comment: @JPillado En ese caso debes tomar en cuenta lo siguiente antes de agregar el dato al array:
1- Que el campo este vacío, entonces lo pones y ya.
2- Que el campo esté ocupado, entonces avanzas hasta encontrar el primer campo vacío y luego retrocedes uno por uno moviendo todo un campo hacia adelante hasta que llegues al campo inicial donde debes meter el dato.
3- Que todo el array este lleno, entonces debes crear un array nuevo más grande, copias todo, y procedes a agregar el dato en el array.
Revisa la respuesta nuevamente, acabo de editar el método `add`.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Ahora toca seguir practicando y así mejorar